# Downgrade to PHP 5.4 on Arch Linux

Tags: php, archlinux, downgrade

I am running a fully updated Manjaro (Arch Linux derivative) distribution with PHP 5.5.6 installed using pacman.

Some scripts I am forced to develop with are not fully compatible with PHP 5.5 yet.

Is there an easy way to downgrade to PHP 5.4 or do I have to compile it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to downgrade packages. Short version of possibilities:

- Look in the `pacman` cache of your computer if the packages are still present (`/var/cache/pacman/pkg`)
- Get old packages from the [Arch Rollback Machine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Rollback_Machine)
- Build the old packages from [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Abs)

The procedures are explained [in the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages). The simplest one will certainly be to look in the cache, or eventually [ARM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Rollback_Machine) if they are not present.